# Java - Auto-Indentation in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I'm making a text-editor in Java, and I have everything I need but auto-indent. How would I make the indentation stay the same if they go to a new line. I'm using a JTextPane for my editor window.

Basically, if a user enters a new line, I want the new line to be indented as was the previous.

Here is my code for the indentation so far:

**Note: My JTextPane is txt, and the `doc` part is the JTextPane's**`DefaultStyledDocument();`

```
SimpleAttributeSet attributes = new SimpleAttributeSet();

TabStop[] tabStops = new TabStop[3];
tabStops[0] = new TabStop(25, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);
tabStops[1] = new TabStop(25, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);
tabStops[2] = new TabStop(25, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);
tabStops[2] = new TabStop(25, TabStop.ALIGN_LEFT, TabStop.LEAD_DOTS);


TabSet tabSet = new TabSet(tabStops);
StyleConstants.setTabSet(attributes, tabSet);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 0, attributes, false);
```

Comment: Try to call doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 1, attributes, false); to include the last paragraph Element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Document Filter:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class NewLineFilter extends DocumentFilter
{
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if ("\n".equals(str))
            str = addWhiteSpace(fb.getDocument(), offs);

        super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
    }

    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        if ("\n".equals(str))
            str = addWhiteSpace(fb.getDocument(), offs);

        super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
    }

    private String addWhiteSpace(Document doc, int offset)
        throws BadLocationException
    {
        StringBuilder whiteSpace = new StringBuilder("\n");
        Element rootElement = doc.getDefaultRootElement();
        int line = rootElement.getElementIndex( offset );
        int i = rootElement.getElement(line).getStartOffset();

        while (true)
        {
            String temp = doc.getText(i, 1);

            if (temp.equals(" ") || temp.equals("\t"))
            {
                whiteSpace.append(temp);
                i++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        return whiteSpace.toString();
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(5, 50);
        AbstractDocument doc = (AbstractDocument)textArea.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter( new NewLineFilter() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("NewLineFilter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane(textArea) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't use that - my JTextPane already has a StyledDocument, and when I add the filter, the syntax highlighting stops working for some reason. If you can help in any way, please do.

Comment: How does your Syntax Highlighting work? Does it also use a DocumentFilter. If so then you can use multiple DocumentFilters by using the approach suggested in [Chaining Document Filters](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/chaining-document-filters/). Another option is to extend StyledDocument and override the insertString() method with the basic code I provided you.

Comment: No, it works by AttributeSets, CharacterAttributes, comparing substrings - but ultimately uses a DefaultStyledDocument.

Comment: Yes I know it uses AttributeSets etc.. But you somehow need to initiate the process of doing the highlighting whenever you add/remove text to the Document. Anyway my two suggestions from above are still valid.

Comment: I run an if statement in the brackets of my DefaultStyledDocument, then when I create the JTextPane, I set the Document to my DefaultStyledDocument.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Why do you set the Document manaually. Did you extend DefaultStyledDocument and override some methods to do the highlighting? If so what methods did you override. Extending the DefaultStyledDocument should not stop the DocumentFilter from working.

Comment: I didn't extend the DefaultStyledDocument. I didn't have to override any methods either.

Comment: The attributes of the Document don't magically change by themselves. You must have some code somewhere that does this. The solution I gave you should not affect changing attributes in the Document. The question has been answered with an appropriate way to do automatic indenting. Your syntax highlighting is the problem. Good luck with your problem.