# Java - Highlighting Text Between two Chars - JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, highlighting, jtextpane

I need to be able to highlight the words within two chars. For example, :

```
//Highlight whatever is in between the two quotation marks
String keyChars = " \" \" ";
```

I have been grueling over this for weeks now. I've looked it up, read source codes, wrote code, and still I have yet to find out how I would be able to do this.

Comment: *"wrote code,"* What have you tried, specifically?  How did it fail?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13449000#13449000) example, it uses a `JEditorPane` but the concept should be the same

Comment: Here is an hint try searching for DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter class. And Check what is a Regex.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to his other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867900/java-auto-indentation-in-jtextpane) where he is trying to do syntax highlighting by playing with AttributeSets. I'm also guessing he is looking for an algorithm to find quoted literals that contain escaped quotes.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In answer to camickr, this isn't really related to that question. Before I asked the question in the link, I didn't have the highlighting quotation marks. Saying that, thanks for all the responses so far!

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet works.

```
ed=new JEditorPane();
ed.setText("This \"text\" contains \"quotes\". The \"contents\" of which are highlighted");
Pattern pl;
pl=Pattern.compile("\"");
Matcher matcher = pl.matcher(ed.getText());
int end=0,beg=0;
while(matcher.find())
{
    beg=matcher.start();
    matcher.find(); //finding the next quote
    end=matcher.start();
    DefaultHighlightPainter d =  new DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);
    try {
        ed.getHighlighter().addHighlight(beg+1, end,d);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, although unfortunately that's not what I was looking for - my fault, because I wasn't clear enough with my question. What I should have said was "live highlighting" between two characters. My bad.